# SQL Insert with different sysdate values

Tags: sql, insert, vertica, sysdate

I am doing an insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE 
(
 ID, 
 SOURCE_ID, 
 DATE_FIELD
) 
SELECT 
 ID,
 *,
 SYSDATE
FROM 
(
 AN SQL QUERY
);
```

When I just run the SELECT part alone, i get values like this:

```
1, 1234, 11.04.2013 15:00:00
1, 1235, 11.04.2013 15:00:00
1, 1236, 11.04.2013 15:00:00
1, 1237, 11.04.2013 15:00:00
1, 1238, 11.04.2013 15:00:00
```

Which is exaclty what i want to insert.

But after running the whole insert I get values like this:

```
1, 1234, 11.04.2013 15:00:01
1, 1235, 11.04.2013 15:00:02
1, 1236, 11.04.2013 15:00:03
1, 1237, 11.04.2013 15:00:04
1, 1238, 11.04.2013 15:00:05
```

Does anybody know why sysdate is behaving this way and what what would be a good workaround?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why sysdate behaves like that but a workaround would be

```
DECLARE @now datetime
SELECT @now = SYSDATE

INSERT INTO TABLE 
(
 ID, 
 SOURCE_ID, 
 DATE_FIELD
) 
SELECT 
 ID,
 *,
 @now
FROM 
(
 AN SQL QUERY
);
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention i am using vertica and they dont have good support for variables

Answer (score 1):

At least according to the 6.1 documentation, each date/time function should give the same timestamp for a given transaction. So if you are getting different results, I would assume that pulling data out of the derived table is happening a little bit at a time.

Try putting sysdate in the derived table and see if that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 1):

This does not explain why SYSDATE does not returns what you expect (and indeed, it is supposed to be stable according to the doc), but maybe you could use NOW() instead?

SYSDATE will always return the same value inside one statement, NOW() will always return the same value inside a transaction. Maybe in the background the INSERT .. SELECT is split in multiple statements (which would surprise me, but this fits the behaviour you see).